# RecycleView doesn't Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

been scowering the internet on this seems to happen a lot for a lot of reasons but I can't solve mine. I can't scroll my RecyclerView and I completly don't know why. 
My recyclerView is included in another layout (activity_class.xml)

Here is my layout code:

**content_home_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF"
    tools:context="com.example.schoolteacher.ClassActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_class">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**activity_class.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.schoolteacher.ClassActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/classes"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_home_screen" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_fab"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any ideas, because I tried almost everything.

Comment: Is any items appearing on the RecyclerView or it can only not scroll?

Comment: Yes the items appear, but it just not scroll.

Comment: Did you check with Layout Inspector tool if there is some view over your RecyclerView, that is stealing focus? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the **content_home_screen** layout

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```